# Raspi python MultiThreading, I want to keep referencing one global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, raspberry-pi

this is my code

`RPi.GPIO` is raspberrypi GPIO input.

**multi threading**

```py
import threading
import time
import test_razer
global email_flag
email_flag = 0

def Mail():
    global email_flag
    while True:
        print("Mail - flipping to 1")
        email_flag = 1
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Mail - flipping to 0")
        email_flag = 0
        time.sleep(5)

def razer():
    global email_flag
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Razer reports flag as:",email_flag)
        test_razer.razer(email_flag)
        

thread_Mail = threading.Thread(target=Mail)
thread_Mail.start()
thread_razer = threading.Thread(target=razer)
thread_razer.start()
```

**test_razer**

```py
import time

def razer(A1):
    while(True):
        print("result: %d"%A1)
        time.sleep(1)
```

**result**

```
Mail - flipping to 1
Razer reports flag as: 1
result: 1
result: 1
result: 1
result: 1
Mail - flipping to 0
result: 1
result: 1
result: 1
result: 1
result: 1
Mail - flipping to 1
result: 1
result: 1
result: 1
result: 1
```

What I want is that the value from `email_flag` is referenced in real time.
However, the value is only referenced the first time the function is called.
`while:razer(email_flag)` is not allowed. In `razer()`, it loads the module of the raspberry pi and there is also a `count` and `while` statement.
There seems to be no way to look for it.
how can i do?

ps.
**original test_razer**

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import VL53L1X
import time
import sys
import signal
from subprocess import call

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
push_red = 22
push_white = 23
GPIO.setup(push_red, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(push_white, GPIO.IN)

#
tof = VL53L1X.VL53L1X(i2c_bus=1, i2c_address=0x29)
tof.open()
tof.start_rangin(1)
running = True

def exit_handler(signal, frame):
        global running
        running = False
        tof.stop_ranging()
        print()
        sys.exit(0)

def runtof(email_flag, main_flag):
        count = 0
        while running:
                if GPIO.input(push_red) == 1 or GPIO.input(push_white) == 1:
                        distance_in_mm = tof.get_distance()
                        print("distance: {}mm".format(distance_in_mm)) #
                        if 0 < distance_in_mm <= 500:
                                count += 1
                                time.sleep(0.3)
                                if count == 3:
                                        count = 0
                                        call(["mpg123", "Razer_voice.mp3"])
                                        time.sleep(1)
                        else:
                                count = 0

                if GPIO.input(push_red) == 0 or GPIO.input(push_white) == 0:
                        while email_flag:
                                time.sleep(1)
                        while main_flag:
                                time.sleep(1)
                        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: `improt ~` ???? And an additional WTH! for the endless recursion in `razer()` (or is it `rager()`?).

Comment: ok, i upload full code

Comment: And please check it for typos!

Comment: Thanks, fixed typos in the code. This code works fine until the button pressed. and may be strange because my English is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, complete rewrite of the answer.
You are going to need to create another module to define, for want of a better description, a `super` global.

N.B. You'll notice that I do not call `test_razer.razer()` where you do, because `test_razer.razer()` itself performs an infinite `while` loop. Instead, I give it, it's own thread. Otherwise main's razer routine would only execute once.

config_var.py

```
email_flag = 0
```

test_razer.py

```
import time
import config_var

def razer():
    while(True):
        print("Test Razer reports: %d"%config_var.email_flag)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

main.py

```
import threading
import time
import config_var
import test_razer

def Mail():
    while True:
        print("Mail - flipping to 1")
        config_var.email_flag = 1
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Mail - flipping to 0")
        config_var.email_flag = 0
        time.sleep(5)

def razer():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Razer reports flag as:",config_var.email_flag)
        #test_razer.razer()
        
thread_Mail = threading.Thread(target=Mail)
thread_Mail.start()
thread_razer = threading.Thread(target=razer)
thread_razer.start()
thread_test_razer = threading.Thread(target=test_razer.razer)
thread_test_razer.start()
```

Results:

```
Mail - flipping to 1
Test Razer reports: 1
Test Razer reports: 1
Razer reports flag as: 1
Test Razer reports: 1
Test Razer reports: 1
Razer reports flag as: 1
Test Razer reports: 1
Test Razer reports: 1
Razer reports flag as: 1
Test Razer reports: 1
Test Razer reports: 1
Razer reports flag as: 1
Test Razer reports: 1
Test Razer reports: 1
Mail - flipping to 0
Razer reports flag as: 0
Test Razer reports: 0
Test Razer reports: 0
Razer reports flag as: 0
Test Razer reports: 0
Test Razer reports: 0
Razer reports flag as: 0
Test Razer reports: 0
Test Razer reports: 0
Razer reports flag as: 0
```

Comment: yes, i tested it. and trying fix.Thanks, but it doesn't "sleep" when I press the button.. so i get a I/0 errer in raspi

Comment: i will uploead result display.

Comment: i up load result.

Comment: @toy339 The updated code is still suspect. What is `self` as the parameter to functions `razer` and `Mail` and why is `razer` calling itself with `razer(email_flag,main_flag)` when it is defined as `razer(self)` and why does `razer` do nothing `but` call itself. I should point out that unless you have a raspberry pi, the full code is impossible to test. This is the reason why SO suggests a minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm really sorry. I made a mistake because it wasn't long after I signed up. I will refer to your code and create and upload the code needed only for the question. sorry.

Comment: i changed my code. And thank you so much for pointing me out without giving up on me. i'm in Korea, so the answer may be late. I am really sorry.

Comment: @toy339 Now I understand. See my revised answer.

Comment: I couldn't even imagine this way. I was too confined to what I learned in school. I respect you. I am embarrassed by my ignorance and think that I should learn more.I learn a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @toy339 Ignorance is nothing to be embarrassed about. It's a condition that can be addressed with the right frame of mind. I do not speak a single word of Korean whilst your English is impressive. 짠!